# Checking if File Exists in Current Directory -- Commands W/in Terminal

Tags: terminal

I've been looking at several other posts on Stackoverflow related to this, and maybe I'm messing them all up, but I'm trying to find a command where I can input the file name into the command and it tells me if that file is in my current directory. Admittedly some of my directories are cluttered and I could organize them, but I'm trying to find a quicker solution.

I've tried grep/ stat but I could've been using it wrong.

If you could structure your posts with "file_name" representing the file input into the command, that'd be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
[ ! -f file_name ] && echo "Not found"
```

**The spacing is very sensitive to the call. If you alter the spacing it will not work as intended.**

Comment: so this  is the simplest? Also, I'm not super well-versed in terminal-speak, so this will just print "Not found" to the terminal if the file isn't found, but otherwise, nothing happens, right?

Comment: It's the simplest way I know of.  And yes, it does nothing if it doesn't exist, as per your original question.